Sequential continuity and the Axiom of Choice
It is well-known that ZF cannot prove the following:
"for a function $f$ from reals to reals and any real $x$,  $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if $f$ is sequentially continuous at $x$."
See e.g. Herrlich's excellent monograph "Axiom of Choice".
What kind of restrictions can one impose on $f$ while keeping the unprovability in ZF?
I am talking about restrictions in the sense of function classes, i.e. semi-continuity or Baire 2.

Let me verify that I understand you correctly. You are asking about a class $C$ of functions, such that the following is not provable in ZF: $\forall f \in C., \forall x \in \mathbb{R} ., (\mathrm{continuous}(f,x)  \Leftrightarrow \mathrm{sequentiallyContinuous}(f,x))$. We know that ZF does not prove the statement when $C$ is the class of all functions, but you'd like a smaller class. Correct?

@AndrejBauer That is exactly what I mean.

If the graph of $f$ has a Borel code $c,$ then ZF proves equivalence of these two continuity concepts. Discontinuity of $f$ at $x$ is downward absolute to $L[c, x],$ in which we can find a sequence $x_i \rightarrow x$ for which it is not the case that $f(x_i) \rightarrow f(x).$
Note that semi-continuous $\rightarrow$ Baire class 1 $\rightarrow$ Baire class 2, and every Baire class 2 function has a Borel code, see: The difference between Baire 2 and 'effectively Baire 2'. So no counterexamples can occur in the cases you list.
Consistently, the equivalence fails for Baire class 3. If $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of countable sets $X_n,$ then every set of reals has a BC3 indicator function. Now let $x=0,$ and let $f$ be the indicator function for $\bigcup_{n<\omega} \{y \in [2^{-n-1}, 2^{-n}]: \forall i<n (y \text{ codes an enumeration of } X_i)\}.$ This is discontinuous at $x,$ but a failure of sequential continuity at $x$ would provide a way to enumerate $\mathbb{R},$ so that can't happen.

Thanks for the nice answer and counterexample.  It seems that the same does not hold for the sequential definition of semi-continuity, i.e. for sequentially usco functions, the local equivalence between continuity and sequential continuity, is not provable in ZF.

Yes, that fails for the indicator function of an infinite Dedekind finite set $S:$ globally sequentially usco, sequentially continuous off $S,$ discontinuous at the condensation points of $S$ (which is a perfect set so is not contained in $S$). If you demanded $f$ be in some Baire class AND usco, it would be significantly harder to find a counterexample.

Indeed, while usco functions are Baire 1, the latter is "hard to prove" at least in higher-order arithmetic.
